# MPI_Iprobe sets flag to 0 when there is message

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

I am trying to probe for messages in order to communicate between MPI processes (8 processes). The first process to reach a certain part of the code will signal all the other processes, and the others will terminate upon reaching there.

Here is what I've implemented: (any simpler solutions are welcome)

```
if(depth == size){
    endTime = MPI_Wtime();
    MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    if(!stat){
        printf("Execution completed in %.5f seconds.\n", endTime - beginTime);
        for (ctr = 0; ctr < mpi_processors; ctr++) {
            if(ctr == mpi_my_pid) continue;
            MPI_Isend(&stat, 1, MPI_INT, ctr, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req);
            printf("sent to %d from %d\n",ctr,mpi_my_pid);

        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The code is self-explanatory. `stat` is a dummy variable just for "send"ing a message, and also used as the flag for the `Iprobe`. The problem is, stat is *always* zero in all processes, meaning that probing doesn't return any waiting messages to be received. But I can confirm that MPI_Isend runs correctly and sends the message.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong, or is there a simple bug somewhere that I can't see?

Thanks,

Can.

Comment: Your code is fundamentally wrong because you do not complete the `MPI_Isend` operation. It might work in your case (e.g. given your MPI implementation) because the message is very small and is likely sent using the eager protocol, but the standard requires that you wait/test the `req` handle.

Comment: how do I do that? I couldn't find any examples involving test/wait. the ones I've found don't have anything related to test/wait.